# Linq-to-EF starting with database first

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I'm coming the Linq-to-SQL world and I want to create a new linq-to-EF6 datacontext.

With Linq-to-SQL, you just create a new data model that outputs a designer onto which you drag and drop tables from an existing database. Here, I tried creating a file with `Add ->` `EF 6.x DbContext Generator` and I'm not getting a designer where I can drag and drop tables from the database; instead I'm getting 2 .tt files that are black. I've looked online and most tutorials are about code-first approach but in my case I already have the database.

What do I need to do to create the datacontext that I can use in Linq-to-EF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add a "`ADO.Net Entity Data Model`" to your project.
2. Create your model from scratch or from an existing database
3. Add a "`EF 6.x DbContext Generator`" to your project.
4. Edit the `Model.tt` file and replace `"$edmxInputFile$"` by the name of your EDMX file
5. Edit the `Model.Context.tt` file and replace `"$edmxInputFile$"` by the name of your EDMX file

The *.tt files are [T4 templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx), which are basically **code that generate code**. Their role here is to parse the EDMX file for you, and generate the associated entities (Model.tt) and DbContext (Model.Context.tt).

To execute a T4 template (for example to update the generated DbContext/entities once you've modified your edmx), right click on the *.tt file and click on "run custom tool".

Answer (score 1):

Add *ADO.NET Entity Data Model* to your project. It will give you the chance to choose existing database as source of the model.